# Distributed caching solution

Tags: caching, memcached, elasticsearch, couchbase

My usecase is to use some data/document store as caching store and want full text search support on that.

I have already used [elastic-search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/) as cache store and that provide full text search. There is only one problem in elastic-search that minimum refresh interval is 1 second. It means after 1 sec the engine provides newly indexed items but we want some real time searching solution.

I have also tried with [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/overview) that is distributed cache solution but couchbase doesn't provide full text search support.

Could anyone suggest any distributed cache solution which supports:

- Data Store with high performance
- Full text search support
- Real time solution i.e. Data inserted should be searchable in milliseconds.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have you tried couchbase with it's [elasticsearch plugin](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/connectors/elasticsearch)? May be adding all you've tried is simplier than searching new solution...

Comment: yes. There is same issue of latency as elastic-search's minimum refresh interval is 1 sec.

Comment: How strict is you requirement about "full text search" in ms? This sounds kind of odd to me to have full text and ms together....

Comment: @user2392692 if you want realtime full text search which is updated in milliseconds you possibly need to write your own indexer that will be optimized only for your database. May be indexes of some data will have priority above others.